# Prevent CSS/JS query hash when preformance is disabled

Tags: theming, caching, performance

When working in a dev environment with performance caching and aggregation turned off is there a standard way to prevent the cache clear hash from being appended to CSS/JS file names?

I'd like to avoiding hooking into the output and removing this manually in a dev only module.

Comment: Just as a side comment, the hash is actually a feature that will update itself automatically when there has been a change to one of the files.  This tells the browser to re-download the CSS/JS files instead of using its internal cached version.  Pretty important for ever-changing sites.

Comment: NOTE: "dev environment". Also the hash doesn't update with a file change, it's on cache clear. This is a major annoyance on development env. You should be aggregating your files on production. The hash feature is actually pretty useless since that mode should never be used except of dev anyway. Plus, it's not reliable in all browsers. Bad choice in Drupal, but I suppose it's for the small sites that don't turn on aggregation.

Comment: You're right, it only changes on cache clear.  But for clarification, what problem comes about from the hash?

Comment: While developing locally you can't see your file changes when refreshing your browser... I certainly don't want to clear cache for every few lines of CSS/JS I update.

Comment: With or without the hash, you will not see any CSS or JS changes unless you do a Force Refresh in your browser. My point was simply that the hash does not create a problem.  The problem is there with or without the hash.

Comment: Not true. Once the hash is gone, a simple refresh will show the change. Suppose it depends on your browser settings though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution (theme based) in template.php

```
function MYTHEME_process_html(&$vars) {
  if (variable_get('environment') == 'development' && !stristr($_GET['q'],'flush-cache')) {
    $vars['styles'] = preg_replace('/\.css\?.*"/','.css"', $vars['styles']);
  }
}
```

NOTE: This assume you have an environment setting in your settings.local.php file like so...
`$conf['environment'] = 'development';` or `$conf['environment'] = 'production';`